# JavaScript Math object

Tags: javascript, math

I am beginner on JavaScript, can sb helpt to answer this question?

Question: What is the math object that returns the smallest integer greater than or equal to a decimal number. Log the answer to the console with the number 43.8 .

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), visit the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and read about [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question.  Note that while homework questions may be allowed, you should mention that it is homework.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 0):

```
console.log(Math.ceil(43.8));
// expected output: 44
```

If you use **Math.ceil**, round up in any case 
e.g:

```
console.log(Math.ceil(43.00858)) // expected output: 44
```

If you use **Math.round**

```
console.log(
Math.round(44.95),      // expected output: 45 
Math.round(44.5),       // expected output: 45 
Math.round(44.05));     // expected output: 44
```